# reference to a value behind a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I want a reference to a value behind a pointer.

```
class UnicastCall {
protected:
    std::fstream *m_stream_attachement_destination_;
...
public:
auto GetStreamAttachementDestination_AsPointer() -> decltype(m_stream_attachement_destination_)
    { return m_stream_attachement_destination_; } //THIS WORKS
auto GetStreamAttachementDestination_AsReference() -> decltype(*m_stream_attachement_destination_) &
    { return *m_stream_attachement_destination_; } //IS THIS CORRECT?
....
};
```

But I get an error.

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
 auto fs = concrete_call->GetStreamAttachementDestination_AsReference();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to copy an `std::fstream`, which is not allowed.

The error is not in your class but **at the call site**. `auto fs = ...` does not create a reference but attempts to call the copy constructor; the `auto` is a substitute only for `std::fstream`, not the `&`.

Try this instead:

```
auto& fs = concrete_call->GetStreamAttachementDestination_AsReference();
```